# How passively monitor for tcp packet loss? (Linux)

Tags: linux, tcp, performance-monitoring, network-monitoring, packetloss

How can I passively monitor the packet loss on TCP connections to/from my machine?

Basically, I'd like a tool that sits in the background and watches TCP ack/nak/re-transmits to generate a report on which peer IP addresses "seem" to be experiencing heavy loss.

Most questions like this that I find of SF suggest using tools like iperf.  But, I need to monitor connections to/from a real application on my machine.

Is this data just sitting there in the Linux TCP stack?

Answer (score 67):

For a general sense of the scale of your problem `netstat -s` will track your total number of retransmissions.

```
# netstat -s | grep retransmitted
     368644 segments retransmitted
```

You can aso grep for `segments` to get a more detailed view:

```
# netstat -s | grep segments
         149840 segments received
         150373 segments sent out
         161 segments retransmitted
         13 bad segments received
```

For a deeper dive, you'll probably want to fire up Wireshark.

In Wireshark set your filter to `tcp.analysis.retransmission` to see retransmissions by flow.

That's the best option I can come up with.

Other dead ends explored:

- netfilter/conntrack tools don't seem to keep retransmits
- stracing `netstat -s` showed that it is just printing `/proc/net/netstat`
- column 9 in /proc/net/tcp looked promising, but it unfortunately appears to be unused.

Comment: and you can monitor the lossed packets with  # watch 'netstat -s | grep retransmited'

Comment: This would show only outbound problems. "netstat -s | grep segments" appears more reasonable to me.

Comment: If you're managing a reasonable sized network, then I'd recommend pastmon over wireshark for continuous monitoring - http://pastmon.sourceforge.net/Wikka-1.1.6.5/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage

Comment: For some reason, it's spelled `retransmited` for me (Ubuntu Server 14).

Comment: what's a good rate for retransmissions vs sent or received ?

Comment: `netstat` doesn't need root for this, BTW.  `/proc/net/netstat` is publicly readable.

Comment: what time period is displayed with the -s option?? Like is it showing stats for last 5 minutes, or since last reboot, or something else?

Answer (score 15):

These stats are in /proc/net/netstat and [`collectl`](http://collectl.sourceforge.net/) will monitor them for you either interactively or written to disk for later playback:

```
[root@poker ~]# collectl -st
waiting for 1 second sample...
#<------------TCP------------->
#PureAcks HPAcks   Loss FTrans
        3      0      0      0
        1      0      0      0
```

Of course, if you'd like to see then side-by-side with network traffic, just include `n` with `-s`:

```
[root@poker ~]# collectl -stn
waiting for 1 second sample...
#<----------Network----------><------------TCP------------->
#  KBIn  PktIn  KBOut  PktOut PureAcks HPAcks   Loss FTrans
      0      1      0       1        1      0      0      0
      0      1      0       1        1      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `ss` tool to get detailed TCP statistics:

```
$ ss --tcp --info
```

Under Debian, use `apt-get install iproute` to get the binary.

Comment: Note that the person asking the question was looking for a tool that they could watch the output of. While some of the commands mentioned so far don't operate this way, all of the upvoted answers included at least one method for doing so.

Comment: @AndrewB: You can do `watch ss -ti`.

Comment: This doesn't include packet loss/retransmit counts in my version of `ss`. I had to use `ss --tcp --options`. That gives you a column at the end which looks like this: `timer:(keepalive,17sec,0)` The retransmission count is the last number; "0" in my case.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some guys at the University of North Carolina (UNC) built a utility to investigate exactly this:

> Methodology
>
> TCP is a classic example of a legacy protocol that gets subject
> to modifications. Unfortunately, evaluation of something as
> fundamental as TCP's loss detection/recovery mechanism is not
> comprehensive. Our aim is to perform a complete realistic evaluation
> of TCP losses and its impact on TCP performance.
>
> I rely on passive analysis of real-world TCP connections to achieve the required level of detail and realism in my analysis.

[http://www.cs.unc.edu/~jasleen/Research-passivetcp.htm#Tool](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Ejasleen/Research-passivetcp.htm#Tool)

> Tool
>
> The purpose of the tool is to provide more complete and accurate
> results for identifying and characterizing out-of-sequence segments
> than those provided by prior tools such as tcpanaly, tcpflows, LEAST,
> and Mystery. Our methodology classifies each segment that appears
> out-of-sequence (OOS) in a packet trace into one of the following
> categories: network reordering or TCP retransmission triggered by one
> of timeout, duplicate ACKs, partial ACKs, selective ACKs, or implicit
> recovery. Further, each retransmission is also assessed for whether it
> was needed or not.

I won't say it is production quality.  Previously I've built quick perl scripts to store ip/port/ack tuples in memory and then report on duplicated data from scanning pcap output, this looks like it provides more thorough analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [`dropwatch`](http://humblec.com/dropwatch-to-see-where-the-packets-are-dropped-in-kernel-stack/) utility.

Comment: It's only available as rpm package  :/

Answer (score 2):

On newer systems, [`netstat`](https://serverfault.com/a/318937/987638) is no longer installed by default. The human-readable frontend for `/proc/net/netstat` has been replaced with `nstat`. The updated commands are as follows:

```
$ nstat | grep Retrans
TcpRetransSegs                  862                0.0
TcpExtTCPLostRetransmit         7                  0.0
TcpExtTCPFastRetrans            5                  0.0
TcpExtTCPSlowStartRetrans       412                0.0
TcpExtTCPSynRetrans             414                0.0
```

```
$ nstat | grep Seg
TcpInSegs                       62529              0.0
TcpOutSegs                      59093              0.0
TcpRetransSegs                  858                0.0
TcpExtTCPDSACKRecvSegs          12                 0.0
```

`nstat -as` can be used to disable the history feature that displays stats since the command was last run so that it will display stats since boot instead. The continuous monitoring command would be `watch 'nstat -as | grep TcpRetransSegs'` .

Answer (score 0):

Apparently good old [sar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) can gather retransmission (and other tcp statistics), along with all kinds of other system statistics that might also be interesting if you investigate a problem like cpu, memory, disk I/O, etc.

You may need to install a package: sysstat and enable this particular kind of statistics with the switch -S SNMP, on RHEL/OracleLinux this is configure in /etc/cron.d/sysstat where /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 is invoked every 5 minutes by default, but that can be tuned also.

For analysis of this data use:

- sar (command line, text based)
- sadf creates SVG according to http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/matrix.html
- ksar (that can plot nice graphs and runs on Java - there are several different clones around from which to choose on sf.net and github if I recall correctly)
- http://www.sargraph.com (based on PHP, with which I have no experience with whatsoever - mind you, the application, not the programming language  )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `/proc/net/snmp` is where the values for `netstat -s` are sourced. So here is quick gawk script to find the % of segments that are retransmitted:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {OFS=" "} $1 ~ /Tcp:/ && $2 !~ /RtoAlgorithm/ {print "InSegs\t",$11,"\nOutSegs\t",$12,"\nRetransSegs\t",$13,"\nPctReTrans\t",($13/$12*100)}' /proc/net/snmp

InSegs   8567261339 
OutSegs  9545034903 
RetransSegs  2192165 
PctReTrans   0.0229665
```

An internal (no public IP or public traffic) AWS instance which we suspected was having networking issues with other systems in the VPC showed **0.0229%** retransmitted, which was over 10 times higher than the **0.002%** max we saw on other nodes. One really bad instance got as high as **2.32%** of all outbound packets were retransmited segments.

You can also see the rate of retransmits during a given time window using:

```
FIRST=$(netstat -s | grep -oP \'\d+(?= segments retransmit+ed)\');
sleep 30;
LAST=$(netstat -s | grep -oP \'\d+(?= segments retransmit+ed)\');
expr $LAST - $FIRST;
```

Comment: looks like nstat is another command for monitoring those counters https://loicpefferkorn.net/2016/03/linux-network-metrics-why-you-should-use-nstat-instead-of-netstat/ `nstat --nooutput;sleep 60;nstat -p TcpRetransSegs TcpExtTCPLostRetransmit TcpExtTCPSynRetrans`

Answer (score 0):

In recent Linux versions, netstat has been replace with `ss` and `ip`. Another answer explains how to use `ss`. With `ip`, you can get the number of dropped packets with this command:

```
ip -s link show eth0
```

See also:

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-dropped-packets-per-interface-command/